# Ruby on rails no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok so I am getting a no method error from this line of code

```
  <%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
```

The issue I think stems from my routes that look like this

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
    resources :comments do
      collection do
        get "by_user_id"
      end
    end
  end
  end
```

I am creating an api but in order to test it I wanted to have the scaffolding forms etc there... is there a way to make these forms work?

Comment: Could you update the question with an exact error message, there are many `NoMethodErrors` possible here.

Comment: You can also think about using rspec + rack::test to test your api. Take a look at http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html in the rspec section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `@comment` is not nil, this should work:

```
<%= form_for([:api, :v1, @comment]) do |f| %>
```